# How to solve the integral $\int\limits_0^a {\frac{{\sqrt {{a^2} - {x^2}} }}{{b - x}}} \mathop{\mathrm{d}x}\\$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have seen this integral:

$$\int\limits_0^a {\frac{{\sqrt {{a^2} - {x^2}} }}{{b - x}}} \mathop{\mathrm{d}x}\\$$

In this integral: $a$ and $b$ are constants.

---

I have try with two ways, but failed:

- $u = \sqrt {{a^2} - {x^2}}$
- $x = a\sin t$

It seems that they are not true-way to solve this integral.

Any suggestion for solving this integral?

---

> Now, I am not a student; so, this is not my exercise.
>   
> Sorry about my English. If my question is not clear, please comment below this question.

Comment: Can we assume $|b|\gt |a|$?

Comment: With the substitution $x=a \sin t$ the integral transforms to $\int_0^{\pi/2}\left[\frac{a^2-b^2}{b-a\sin t}+b+a\sin t\right]dt$

Answer (score 3):

First off I would let $x=-a\cos\theta$. Then
$$\begin{align}\int_0^a\frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{b-x}dx&=\int_{\frac{\pi}2}^{\pi}\frac{a^2\sin^2\theta}{b+a\cos\theta}d\theta\\
&=\int_{\frac{\pi}2}^{\pi}\frac{a^2(1-\cos^2\theta)}{b+a\cos\theta}d\theta\\
&=\int_{\frac{\pi}2}^{\pi}\left(-a\cos\theta+b+\frac{a^2-b^2}{b+a\cos\theta}\right)d\theta\end{align}$$
Now that last term may look a little intimidating, but [I just did it this morning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1740458/finding-int-fracdxab-cos-x-without-weierstrass-substitution/1741835#1741835), so we get$$\begin{align}\int_0^a\frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{b-x}dx&=\left[-a\sin\theta+b\theta+\frac{a^2-b^2}{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{b\cos\theta+a}{b+a\cos\theta}\right)\right]_{\frac{\pi}2}^{\pi}\\
&=a+b\frac{\pi}2+\sqrt{b^2-a^2}\left(\cos^{-1}\left(\frac ab\right)-\pi\right)\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$\int_0^a {\frac{{\sqrt {{a^2} - {x^2}} }}{{b - x}}}dx=
\int_0^a\frac{b+x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}-\frac{b^2-a^2}{(b-x)\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\ dx
$$

where $\int_0^a\frac{b+x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx
= a+\frac{b\pi}2$
\begin{align} 
\int_0^a\frac{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}{(b-x)\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx
= &\ \tan^{-1}\frac{a^2-bx}{\sqrt{(b^2-a^2)(a^2-x^2)}}\bigg|_0^a
=\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}a
\end{align}