# How to integrate $\int \frac{\cos x}{1+a\cos x}\ dx$?

Tags: integration

How to integrate 
$$\int \frac{\cos x}{1+a\cos x}\ dx$$
where $a$ is a constant. I've tried substitution, tangent half angle substitution, breaking the fraction apart, and even the typical $u$ $\dfrac{dv}{dx}$ method. Nothing seems to work. Can anyone help?

Comment: You have asked this a while before. The tangent-half-angle substitution would work. Note that $\sin^2(x) +\cos^2(x) =1 $.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1740458/finding-int-fracdxab-cos-x-without-weierstrass-substitution?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3):

If you used the tangent half-angle substitution, you ended with 
$$I=\int\frac{2-2 t^2}{-a t^4+a+\left(t^2+1\right)^2}\,dt$$
Using partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{2-2 t^2}{-a t^4+a+\left(t^2+1\right)^2}=\frac 2a \left(\frac{1}{(a-1) t^2-(a+1)}+\frac{1}{t^2+1}\right)$$ which looks quite simple.